# Create a column chart with minimum height columns

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I'm trying to create a column chart with minimum pixel height columns. This is easy in chartjs (set the `minBarLength` property), however I can't figure out how to do so in amcharts.

I've tried setting `series.column.template.minHeight` to no effect. I've also tried setting `pixelHeight` and `height`, but also with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

one workaround can be using scrollbar in Y axis like this following:

```
chart.scrollbarY = new am4core.Scrollbar();
chart.scrollbarY.start = 0;
chart.scrollbarY.end = 0.08;
```

with value Axis

```
    valueAxis.min = 0;
    valueAxis.max = 10;
```

This is not the best solution i agree but you can use it to slightly zoom with the buttons and scale and see

let me know if it works!